# Export Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that includes custom App Script. I need to:

1. Download a copy of the sheet.
2. Zip up the sheet.
3. Send it to another user.

Is there a way to do this in Google Sheets? For privacy reasons, I can't just send a link to the Google Sheet. That's why I need to download the sheet, zip it up, and send it via email so the person can import it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to download a Google spreadsheet including a bounded / contained Google Apps Script project.

The easiest way is to share the spreadsheet as view so the other party could make a copy but if you really need to "download" it you have to do two downloads and other things:

1. Spreadsheet. This could be done from Google Drive or Google Sheets UI.
2. Google Apps Script project for this you might use the Google Apps Script API or CLASP (a command line tool that use the Google Apps Script API.
3. Zip both files either in separate zip files or on a single one
4. Send the zip by email
5. The recipient will have to convert the spreadsheet into Google Sheets format
6. Using the Google Apps Script UI, API or CLASP create a bounded project
7. "Push" the Google Apps Script project files to the project created in the previous step.

The above assuming that the Google Apps Script project is using the default Google Cloud project but if it's using a Google Cloud Standard project there are more might be more things to do.